# Filter by presence in a model's set

Tags: python, django

I have a `Customer` model that has many `Location`s, i.e., there is a location_set attribute on the model that returns a list of locations. Each `Location` also has many customers, i.e., a customer_set attribute.

I have one customer instance with all of its corresponding attributes. What I want to do is return all other customers who are present in at least of the locations in the customer's location_set. Is there a clean way to do this without having to manually manipulate the queryset and make a ton of calls to the DB?

```
class Customer(AbstractUser):

    current_location = models.ForeignKey('device.Location',
            null=True, blank=True, related_name='customers_present')
    default_location = models.ForeignKey('device.Location',
            null=True, blank=True, related_name='default_customers')

class Location(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="The name of the location")
    customers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            through='customer.Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    location = models.ForeignKey('device.Location')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: please post your model definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your model definitions it is very difficult to provide an exact answer to your question, something like the below could work:

`Customer.objects.filter(location__in=your_customer_instance.location_set.all()).exclude(pk=your_customer_instance.pk)`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something like that. Unfortunately customer doesn't have a single location attribute, so I'm not sure that query would work. :-( Unless location__in is actually smart enough to iterate over the items in a set on its own? See the above edits.

Comment: `location` should follow the m2m relationship, if you do a `filter` with incorrect kwargs the exception will show you all available filter kwargs (even reverse)